# How do I write Ruby in terminal to extract twitter handles from a paragraph of text?

Tags: ruby

If I have a paragraph of @text and I want to extract the @twitter handles from it and make them into a list, how would I do this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use String#scan

Use the [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method to extract your expression into an array. For example:

```
str = <<'EOF'
  If I have a paragraph of @text and I want to extract the
  @twitter handles from it and make them into a list, how
  would I do this?
EOF

str.scan /@\S+/
#=> ["@text", "@twitter"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful. The regex /@\S+/ will take "Hi @user.How are you" and extract "@user.How". To avoid that, this regex worked better for me /@[a-zA-Z\d_-]+/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your @text is a string, use regex to extract @twitter handles and add them into an array.